# Replication and effect on performance

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

As far as I know, replication in MongoDB is a way to keep same data set in different servers on `mongod`s. I read the MongoDB documentation but I didn't find anything related to performance changes.

There's always a question for me that can replication help MongoDB in write/read operation performance or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The performance shouldn't be affected by this. The primary does not replica down but rather the secondaries and other members "pick" form the primaries oplog, which is basically a journal of operations.

I suppose there is a performance hit in the storage of the oplog, you do need some extra disk space.

> There's always a question for me that can replication help MongoDB in write/read operation performance or not?

Not write no, you can only ever write to the primary and since reads are concurrent and you have a writer greedy lock you don't have write performance gains.

As for reads; well the vote is out on that. Since the members of the set get just as many OPs as the primary and in turn just as much weight many say that actually it doesn't help at all, however, they do concede that in certain cases (analytics reporting) it does help.

Of course the reads will always return stale data, i.e. data that might have changed/deleted.

Really whether replica reads will benefit you or not is up to your scenario and we do not know enough to tell you yes or no.

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer. So, the goal of replication is to provide a high available MongoDB server, not to boost the performance or I/O. correct?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani yeah really, sharding is what you are recommendfed to look at

Comment: The goal of the replication is not performance gain in the first place. The goal is to secure data and provide high availability. On the other hand if your setup consist of enough nodes you may choose nearest read preference for your replicaset which in geologically distrubutes systems can reduce the lataceny it takes to fetch data. So that way it can be helpfull.

Comment: Replication actually is a performance measure as well, you touched on it a little, but in dc awareness with partitions replication becomes a performance case and MongoDB actually built it with that intention, whether or not they admit that now; I do not know, however, back years ago that was the original intention. But even in non dc environments replication can help to produce cached reads from secondaries which is quite important for high traffic sites that normally use memcached for this